# doseq should be giving me side effects so why does it work with dorun only?

Tags: clojure

I wrote a simple program which takes a number n and a list as input. And then prints each element in the list n times.

I initially tried this

```
(defn list-repl [num lst]
  (doseq [elem lst]
    (map println (repeat num elem))))
```

This didn't work. No output. Then while looking at the docs I found `dorun`. I tried this and it did work.

```
(defn list-repl [num lst]
  (doseq [elem lst]
    (dorun (map println (repeat num elem)))))
```

Reading the documentation what I could understand is that [doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) is a like a looping construct which forces side-effects in its body-expression. [dorun](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dorun) also does that directly for sequences.

Is this understanding correct? If it is correct then the body in the first example should have given me the side effect of printing the number. But that did not happen. So what is missing in my understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `doseq` can't force every side effect in its body. In order to guarantee that it would have to recursively check every expression in its body for lazy subcomputations to force, which would be... challenging. It only deals with the top-level expressions. Forcing any lazy subcomputations is the job of the expressions' writer.

If you need several layers of looping to "unpack" members of an outer sequence, remember that `doseq`, `for` and other variants all support nested loops by providing more than one binding:

```
(defn list-repl [num lst]
  (doseq [elem lst
          to-print (repeat num elem)]
    (println to-print)))
```